# Отправка файлов на сервер jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Форма

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=""
 class="gi--form" id="gi--form">
            <input type="file" class="addfile" data-placeholder="attach" id="file_third">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760" /> 

            <input type="text" name="file" placeholder="describe idea" id="describe_third">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="third" placeholder="name" id="name_third">
            <input type="tel" data-format="+38 (ddd) dd dd ddd"  name="number" class="third" placeholder="tel" id="tel_third">
            <div class="ready_t"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="send" id="third" onclick="tirdSend();">

        </form>
```

js код:

```
function thirdSend() {
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#gi--form").on('#third',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "mail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                $(".ready_t").html(data);
            }           
       });
    }));
});
}
```

PHP (mail.php):

```
if( isset( $_POST[third] )){
    print_r($_FILES[file_third]);
}
```

В результате ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо data:  `new FormData(this),` прописать `data: {third:new FormData(this)},`

Comment: У вас очепятка: `onclick="tirdSend();"`